# JSON: cannot unmarshal string

Tags: json, powershell, graphql

I'm trying to use a Rest API, but when I query, I receive the following error that I don't understand, I've tried to look at similar questions here but they are very particular cases. 
This is the code I use

```
$oAuth2TokenUrl = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql"
$accessKey = '1234'

$Cloudflare_Oauth_Header = @{
    "X-AUTH-EMAIL" = "bryan";
    "X-AUTH-KEY" = "$accessKey";
    "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

$query = '\"query\": \"{
  viewer {
zones(filter: {zoneTag: \"1234\"}) {
  httpRequests1mGroups(orderBy: [datetimeMinute_ASC], limit: 1000, filter: {datetime_geq: \"2020-05-07T10:00:00Z\", datetime_lt: \"2020-05-07T10:10:00Z\"}) {
    dimensions {
      datetimeMinute
    }
    sum {
      browserMap {
        pageViews
        uaBrowserFamily
      }
    }
    uniq {
      uniques
    }
  }
}
  }
    } \"' | ConvertTo-Json    

$Cloudflare_zone = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $oAuth2TokenUrl -Method POST -Headers $Cloudflare_Oauth_Header -Body $query -ContentType 'application/json'
```

So once I check the content of `$Cloudflare_zone` the following is printed

`{@{message=failed to recognize JSON request: 'json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type graphql.httpPostBody'; path=; extensions=}}`

Comment: I assume you are trying to [authenticate](https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/graphql-api/getting-started/)? It doesn't look like it requires a body to the request, just the two headers you have specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says *"json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type graphql.httpPostBody"*.

This boils down to "Cannot parse the JSON string you sent". And sure enough, your JSON string is invalid.

It becomes much easier to handle when you split it up: A string variable with the GraphQL, and a PowerShell hashtable with your request body. The hash table is can then be converted to JSON for transfer.

```ps1
$graphQL = '{
  # whatever (note the single quotes, so any double quotes in here can stay unescaped)
}'

$header = @{
  "X-AUTH-EMAIL": "bryan"
  "X-AUTH-KEY": "$accessKey"
}

$body = @{
   query: $graphQL
   # potentially other parameters that are not part of the GraphQL
}

$Cloudflare_zone = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql" `
  -Method POST `
  -Headers $Cloudflare_Oauth_Header `
  -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json) `
  -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Notes:

- I've used line continuation (by escaping the newline with backticks) to break up the line for increased readability.
- It's generally a good idea to specify the charset explicitly, as opposed to letting `Invoke-RestMethod` do whatever it wants.
- You should convert all of this to a PowerShell function for easier reuse.

Comment: Yes, this worked. So I should split it up instead of just doing all like I did.
Thank you so much.